# Styles are not taking in for no button

Tags: html, css

When I change the color of the "no button" it's not changing.
When I debug it I found out that it is over written by some other color.
How can I fix it? 
It's working for "yes button", but not working for "no button".

http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/15/

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">eWaste</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input name="Finish" 
               style="width:70px; background-color:#0e6a91; height:24px;" 
               value="Yes"
               type="submit" >
        <input style="width:70px; height:24px; background-color: #la4567;"
               name="Finish" 
               value="No"
               type="submit" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Notes</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea rows="3" cols="80" style="width: 280px;"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is darker blue is the color you want?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the colour of the `no` button. You have `#la4567`. `l` (lower case L) is not a valid hex character. Did you intend for this to be a `1` (one)?

```
#1a4567
```